# Adding name value with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

I'm using a `link_to` to create an object in my Rails 3 app. Searching has given me the proper way to use `link_to` with the `:post` method, but I'm wondering if using `link_to` to pass in a name value for my object as well. Here is my link:

```
<%= link_to "Todo text", {:controller => "profiles", :action => "create_inside", :method => :post}, :class => "button white" %>
```

**My `profiles_controller.rb`:**

```
def create_inside
    @todo = Insidetodo.new
    @todo.save!
    if @todo.save
      redirect_to @profile.todo, :notice => 'Todo successfully added.'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

**My `todo.rb` model:**

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

Is there a way to add in `:name => "#{@user.profile.todotext}"` to the `link_to` so that it passes and saves? I don't know if it's creating properly because at the moment when I click a `link_to` I get a validation error - `Validation failed: Name can't be blank`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passing `name` in the `link_to`

```
<%= link_to "Todo text", {:controller => "profiles", :action => "create_inside", :name => "#{@user.profile.todotext}", :method => :post}, :class => "button white" %>
```

and the controller must be

```
def create_inside
  @todo = Insidetodo.new(:name => params[:name])
  if @todo.save
    redirect_to @todo.goal, :notice => 'Todo successfully added.'
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

But the `link_to` will pass the name parameter in url only(like `<a href="/profiles/create_inside?name=xxx">Todo text</a>`).

If you want the name not to be sent in the url, you might want to use a form and use a submit button instead of the link as it is representing an action and not a link.

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "profile", :action => "create_profile") do -%>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :name, @user.profile.todotext %>
  <%= submit_tag "Todo Text" %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Is using `form_tag` the only way to execute that action properly? I wanted to use `link_to` in particular because it keeps my code cleaner.

Comment: actually you should be using `button_to` if your making POST requests

Comment: Gotcha, are there any other ways to keep the name out of the URL?